# how to use input.value in javascript

Tags: javascript

hey please help me fix my code

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var v = input.value;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(v);
  p.appendChild(text)
  main.appendChild(p)
})
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>fr testing purppose</h1>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</div>
```

i would be very grateful to person who would help me..

Comment: Could you please add what the exact error is you are getting? It'll help people answering your question.

Comment: You were getting the element value before the click event - move the code where you get the value within the click event handler. E.g. `var text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("input").value);`

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the snipped for you.

The problem was, you had declared variable `v` outside event listener for the button, and using it inside the event listener body.

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var v = input.value;
  input.value = null;
  var text = document.createTextNode(v);
  p.appendChild(text)
  main.appendChild(p)
})
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>fr testing purppose</h1>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", mf);

function mf(){
  
  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var v = input.value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(v);
  p.appendChild(text)
  main.appendChild(p)
};
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>fr testing purppose</h1>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get the current input value when you click that button.

```
var text = document.createTextNode(input.value);
```

It will fix your code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const list = document.querySelector("ul")

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(input.value != "") {
    const listItem = document.createElement("li")
    listItem.innerText = input.value
    list.appendChild(listItem);
    input.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>Add</button>
</form>

<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.
Actually you were declare variable v before creating of button event listener.

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
*// var v = input.value;*
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var v = input.value;
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(v);
    p.appendChild(text);
    main.appendChild(p);
});
```